# Loading 50K + rows rows in an Optimized way to jQuery DataTable for better performance in MVC Entity Framework application

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have checked many forums and other questions related to this issue but none helped. I am writing a .net MVC application that uses Entity framework. For one of the controller actions I am loading data from a stored procedure which is just a select statement and returns 50k + rows. In SQL server side the performance is fine.. It takes only 3 secs to retrieve the rows but the real problem comes when the page is getting loaded. I am using jQuery datatable from Datatables.net to show the data. 
As i have observed the page is loading all the rows at first so I am getting an infinite scrolling at first then it is applying the pagination which comes with the datatable.
It is taking forever to load it. I have tried Server side processing as it is mentioned on the site , I have tried deferred rendering as mentioned here https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html as well.. 
none worked.

My Controller code :

```
private DB_Entities db = new DB_Entities();
public ActionResult Staff()
        { 

            var DetailsData = new DataViewModel { IDDetails = db.Get_IDDetails().ToList<Get_IDDetails_Result>(), Name = "Staff" };
            return View(DetailsData );
        }
```

Table-Loader JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*used to change default show entry value to 25*/
    $('#ex').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferLoading": 25
    });
});
```

CSHTML code:

```
<tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model.IDDetails)
{
<tr>
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employeeName)
</td>
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EID)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Accountid)
</td>
</tr>
 }

</tbody>
```

Any idea how can I optimize these many rows or load them in a better way or any other ways to optimize it ??

Comment: You need to perform all paging and filtering logic on the server side. Doing any of that on the client will kill performance with a recordset of the size you have

Comment: Loading 50k+ rows in *any* way will never have any sort of performance - so I guess "better" is relative, but *even* better would be server-side.

Comment: Datatables has built-in functionality for server-side paging, they have examples on their site and may even include an MVC example.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan -  can you please explain how can I apply that on server side?? Any link or forum I can get this information?

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: Also see: https://www.datatables.net/faqs/index "DataTables is running slow. How can I speed it up?"   about 1/3 of the way down